# Show stdout containing \n with line breaks

Tags: bash, echo, newlines

The output from an executable (cURL) contains \n. How can such output be displayed with line breaks?

Say the output from an executable is `tCL\n1523 memo\n`, piping to printf does not show line breaks.

```
$ echo "tCL\n1523 memo\n"
tCL\n1523 memo\n
$
$ printf "tCL\n1523 memo\n"
tCL
1523 memo
$
$ echo "tCL\n1523 memo\n" | xargs -0 printf '%s'
tCL\n1523 memo\n
$
$ echo "tCL\n1523 memo\n" | awk '{ printf "%s", $0 }
tCL\n1523 memo\n
```

Comment: That is because *echo* does only interpret sequences as \n if you use the switch **-e**.

Comment: @Janka: In this case OP actually wants `echo` to **not** interpret the newlines as they are using `echo` to simulate the `curl` output that needs to be interpreted.

Answer (score 7):

`%s` does not interpret escape sequences. You need `%b` for that:

```
% echo 'tCL\n1523 memo\n' | xargs -0 printf "%b"
tCL
1523 memo

%
```

Comment: Nice one!  I still think command substitution would be better than xargs though, no?

Comment: Possibly. In either case the entire output ends up as an argument, and with command substitution the extra xargs step is avoided.

Comment: @muru Thanks for your solution ! I wonder how to make awk printf also work, given %b is not available ?

Comment: You'll probably have to use the input as the format string, after replacing all `%` with `%%`

Comment: @muru `printf $0` wouldn't work because escape characters are expanded where the format string is defined, not where it's used, so the 2-char string `\n` in $0 will remain as such even in  the context of a printf format string. You could do `gsub()`s but then you might run afoul of `\\n`s. There simply is no equivalent functionality in awk and any workaround would be clunky at best.

Comment: I just added said clunky workaround - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/534944/133219.

Answer (score 5):

You probably need to transform double-backslash to backslash as well, otherwise the input format would be ambiguous.

You can write a sed script to translate backslash-letter escapes. This script only translates the escape sequences that it recognizes and otherwise removes the backslash. I've put in support for newline and tab.

```
… | sed 's/\\n/\n/g; s/\\t/ /; s/\\\(.\)/\1/g'
```

The whitespace in `s/\\t/   /` is a tab character. GNU sed lets you write `s/\\t/\t/`.

If you also want octal escapes, use a more advanced tool such as Perl. You can make it parse all the escape sequences that it supports.

```
… | perl -pe 's/\\([0-7]{1,3}|c.|[oxN]\{[^{}]+\}|.)/"\"\\${1}\""/eeg'
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's what it'd take to do what you want with awk. Given this input:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'abc\\ndef\nghi'
abc\\ndef\nghi
```

Note that the first `\n` is itself escaped and so should be treated literally as `\\n`. Here's how to get the expected output:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'abc\\ndef\nghi' |
    awk '{gsub(/@/,"@A"); gsub(/\\\\/,"@B"); gsub(/\\n/,"\n"); gsub(/@B/,"\\\\"); gsub(/@A/,"@")}1'
abc\\ndef
ghi
```

If you want other escape sequences interpreted too, e.g. `\t`, you'd add a separate gsub() for each of those right after the one for `\n`, e.g.:

```
awk '{
    gsub(/@/,"@A"); gsub(/\\\\/,"@B")
    gsub(/\\n/,"\n")
    gsub(/\\t/,"\t")
    gsub(/@B/,"\\\\"); gsub(/@A/,"@")
}1'
```

Those first 2 and last 2 gsub()s are creating a unique string `@B`, mapping `\\` pairs to it to get them out of the way, and then mapping them back after the intended conversions are done.

Answer (score 0):

Easy enough:  `echo -e "tCL\n1523 memo\n"`

From `man echo`:

`-e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes`